# Windows Console in Explorer Context Menu

Tags: windows, windows-explorer, console, context-menu

Is there a way to bring up a Windows console (for the current directory) from the Windows Explorer context menu?  I really like this feature in Nautilus (on Linux) and I'm wondering if there is a parallel feature in Windows.

**Edit:**
I'm specifically interested in Windows 7 and Windows XP.

Comment: What version of windows?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can use [power toys](http://www.microsoft.com/windowsxp/Downloads/powertoys/Xppowertoys.mspx) 'Open Command Window Here' for Windows XP to open a command window pointing directly at the selected folder.

**EDIT**

I'm not a Windows 7 user (yet) but apparently if you press the 'Shift' key and right-click on any folder, you get some extra options like "Open Command Window Here".

See [here](http://www.askvg.com/enable-open-command-window-here-option-in-context-menu-in-windows-vista/) for more info on this, it demonstrates how to enable this feature without pressing shift using some registry tweaks.

Comment: Excellent! Do you know if there is a similar tool for Windows 7?

Comment: Link : http://download.microsoft.com/download/whistler/Install/2/WXP/EN-US/CmdHerePowertoySetup.exe

Comment: Already there in Win7 with shift-right-click.

Comment: Has been that way since Vista, even.

Comment: The link in this answer appears to be broken now. :/

Answer (score 4):

The following text, when entered into a .reg file and launched, will do it:

> ```
> Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00
>
> [HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Directory\shell\CommandPrompt]
> @="Open Command Window Here"
>
> [HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Directory\shell\CommandPrompt\command]
> @="cmd.exe /k pushd %L"
> ```

Answer (score 4):

You can do this in the registry (normal "editing the registry" warnings apply)

1. Create a new key under `HKLM\Software\Classes\Folder\Shell`, name it **Command Prompt**.  Set the default string value to whatever you want to see in the context menu when you right-click on a folder
2. Create a new key under the one you created in step 1 and call it **command**
3. Set the default value of the key you created in step 2 to this:
   `%SystemRoot%\system32\cmd.exe /k pushd %1`

Now when you right-click a folder you'll have an item that says **Command Prompt** that will open a cmd prompt window to that folder.  You can use any valid reg string for the key name in step 1.

Comment: how can you make this context show also when you are inside a folder?